# How to make a request to a local API running on localhost using the local IP in Postman in C#

Tags: c#, .net, postman, localhost, ip

I am developing an api that has to communicate with another api. Before the deployment I want to test it and also in debug mode other api's sandbox able to send requests to my api using my ip adress. So I want to try it on postman first.

I tried to send request like `https://192.168.1.100:3000/api/Controller/getAll` from postman then I get error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.100:3000

I tried both Postman proxy settings closed and open and got same error.
Other postman request like `https://localhost:3000/api/Controller/getAll` to localHost works perfectly.

Comment: Good point. I forgot the http's' but it did not change anything still the same error result.

Comment: Your server needs to listen 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your app's listening IP.

on launchSettings.json:

<s>`'applicationURL' = 'https://localhost:3000'`</s>

`'applicationURL' = 'https://192.168.1.100:3000'`